# what are these metrics called ?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

could anyone please tell me if the following metrics have specific names, i'm just trying to label some notes.

**function spaces**

$\forall f,g \in[0,1]$

$ d (f,g)=sup_{x \in[0,1]} \lvert f(x)-g(x) \rvert$

$d(f,g)= \int_o^1 \lvert f(x)-g(x) \rvert dx$

**sequence spaces**

Let $c_0$ be the set of all sequences $(x_k)$ of real numbers which converge to
$ 0 $. Then $(c_0, d)$ is a metric space where we define

$d(x,y)= sup_k \lvert x_k - y_k \rvert $

Answer (score 2):

The first is called the $L^\infty$ metric.

The second is called the $L^1$ metric.

The third is called the $\ell^\infty$ metric.

All of these are more likely to be called "the metric induced by the _ norm".

Comment: does L stand for anything or do we just say for example, the   L infinity metric

Comment: @exodius It's just pronounced as "L infinity" or similar. I think the usage of $L$ is to refer to Lebesgue, since these are closely related to Lebesgue integration.

Comment: ah yes that would make sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The function $f\mapsto\sup|f|$ (when it makes sense) is a norm which is usually called the [supremum norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SupremumNorm.html) and denoted by $\|f\|_\infty$. So, the distance $(f,g)\mapsto\|f-g\|_\infty$ is the distance induced by the supremum norm.